# Monitor http traffic going from localhost wordpress on Fiddler

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, fiddler, network-traffic

I want to monitor all HTTP requests going to the internet from a locally deployed Wordpress instance (on XAMPP server) on Fiddler. I guess I may need to configure XAMPP (or php specifically) to route all the requests going from it to the internet via Fiddler proxy but I am not sure how to do that. Has someone done this before?

**Flow:**
1. Wordpress (on a local XAMPP instance) makes an ajax call to the internet via a plugin.
2. I want to check the HTTP request and response for debugging.
3. I configured Fiddler to monitor localhost traffic but that does not show me requests sent by XAMPP.
4. Stuck!

Comment: Well you can use software such as Wireshark to monitore all of your traffic.

Comment: Or you can use software such as postman to test different POST and GET requests

Comment: @Clomez I know what tools can be used to monitor network traffic. Point is how do I configure XAMPP to route all it's internal requests via Fiddler proxy.